# Remove all instances of an element from a collection

Tags: java, object, collections, recursion

I need to remove all elements from a collection c that are less than a given object.

The signature should be `void removeLess(Collection c, Object o)`

Would something like this work?:

```
void removeLess(Collection c, Object o) {
    Iterator<Integer> itr = c.iterator();
    while (itr.hasNext()) {
        if (itr.next.compareTo(o) < 0) {
            c.remove(o);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: _"Would something like this work?"_, why not try it?

Comment: answers explain why this won't work, but also, I don't think that `o` is really what you mean to be removing anyway.

Comment: and `o` has to be an `Integer` for this to work.  In the next release of Guava you could do all this as just `Iterables.removeIf(c, Ranges.lessThan(o))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `c.remove(o)` or you invalidate the iterator; but you can use the optional method `Iterator.remove()`, as in `itr.remove()`. It removes the last object returned from "next".

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it would, provided that the `Collection` class's `Iterator` supports the `remove` method.

And you have a syntax error - should be `itr.next()`.

Also, try it?

Comment: He doesn't call itr.remove(), he calls c.remove(o).

Comment: Yea just noticed that. There are several things wrong with the code.

Answer (score 0):

No, it won't work since you can't modify a collection while there is an `Iterator` over it. You should accumulate elements that you will remove into another temporary collection and remove them all afterwards.

A better approach, if you don't care about the indices in which the element reside, would be to use the `TreeSet<T>` class which, by structure, provides the method `tailSet(T element)` which does exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use the `Iterator`'s `remove` method instead, and the signature would need to be:

```
<E extends Comparable<? super E>> void removeLess(Collection<E> c, E o)
```

With a `NavigableSet<E>` such as a `TreeSet`, you could just do:

```
set.headSet(o).clear();
```